# How to get raw output of showkey for use in a script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, keyboard, timeout

I want to get the output of `showkey` for use in a script, without the 10 second limitation.

Comment: Look into the timeout command

Answer (score 2):

A GNU coreutils utility:

```
timeout 1s showkey ...
```

This will wait 1 second for the `showkey ...` command to exit; if it has not exited in that time, [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) will send a SIGTERM to it. There are other options for the duration (seconds, minutes, hours, days).